# In SSRS. I am trying to create a SSRS report that creates a new page per row of data and inserts into an identical template per each page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS. I am trying to create an SSRS report that creates a new page per each row of data from the query in the shared dataset. It will then inserts the values under the text boxes. The template will be the same on every page. How would I do that specifically? My end goal is to produce a report in the form of a PDF, that inserts data in a template under each header/text title, and creates a new page/template for each record/row of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main options here.

**Option 1: Row Groups**
Create a row group that groups by something that makes your records unique (may an ID column or similar).

Within that row group add as many rows as you need to place all your text boxes.

On the row group pproperties set the page breaks to "between each instance"

**Option 2: Sub reports**
The method is a little more long winded but I find it easier to maintain.

Create a report that accept a parameter that identifies a single record. For example if each record has a unique ID,  something like

```
ID    FirstName    LastName
1     Dave         Smith
2     Bob          Jones
3     Mary         Scary
```

then create a report that accepts ID as a parameter.

Your dataset query would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = @ID
```

Build your report as you want so it will produce a report for 1 record.

Once this is tested and working, create a new 'master' report.

Add a dataset query that returns the records you want to report on. In our simple example this might be something like

```
SELECT ID FROM myTable
```

Add a table to your report and set it's dataset property to the dataset you just created.
Next on the detail row of the table in the first cell, right click and choose "Insert => Subreport".

Right-click the subreport placeholder and set the subreport to point to the subreport we created earlier. on the parmaters tab in the subreport properties, click "add" and choose the parameter name on the left side. On the right under "value" select your ID column from the dataset.

You can remove any blank rows/columns and that should be it.

On the details row group, set page breaks to be "between each instance"

When the report runs, it will produce one row per record and in each row a copy of your sub report will be generated one for each record.

Comment: Whenever I set the group properties set page break to "Between each instance" it will put a new template on ever single plage? automatically? By template, I mean the same title text boxes/headers on the initial page.

Comment: Also, just know, that it's not a table. The headers are just simple text boxes

Comment: It will repeat whatever is inside the group, or repeat whatever is in your subreport design depending on which option you choose.

Comment: Take a look at one of my old answers, the principle is the same, you just need to set the group properties to "between each instance" (I don't think that is mentioned in this old answer)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926767/show-multiple-line-chart-in-ssrs/59935810#59935810

Comment: I don't know how to get Row Groups or Column Groups within the SSRS report because I am not using a table. I am simply dragging the Dataset fields onto the report and labeling them with a custom text box. It is not allowing me to add Row Groups or Column Groups.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use the subreport method I described. You will only need a table in the main report. Use your current report as the subreport but limit it to only show one record via a parameter, then add the main report.